# Reveal Symbolic Link in Finder, NOT the file it resolves to?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, symlink, alias

I wrote the following script to select copied/pasted Finder items in the target folder I pasted them into.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thePath to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
    set theFiles to paragraphs of (the clipboard)
    set theOutput to {}
    set theFile to {}
    
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theFiles
        set theFile to POSIX file (thePath & item i of theFiles) as text
        set end of theOutput to theFile as text
    end repeat
    
    reveal theOutput
    activate
    
end tell
--return theOutput
```

It works great on most files and folders alike, even those that might have `"` somewhere in the name.

However, when the copied/pasted files are a symbolic link, Finder resolves them to the original files instead of selecting/revealing the link files (which is what I am aiming to achieve).

Is there some way to change the script to make it not follow/resolve link files to their target and reveal the link files themselves in Finder instead?

Comment: That's what `reveal` does — it is basically the applescript equivalent of the finder's `show original` (which I think even used to be called 'reveal'). Try using the `select` command. Also, while looking through your script, I don't really see the advantage of all the coercing that's being done.

Comment: @Mockman Thanks for the reply. I'm sure it could be a lot simpler. This is just what I came up with to resolve some hiccups I was seeing between selecting one item vs several. I'm far from an Applescript expert. but regarding what you wrote, i use an Automator service to create the symlinks via shell script, which also echoes & reveals/selects them in Finder afterwards - not their targets. So it seems possible, but I'm not sure how to do it beyond that point after copying/moving them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below, the 'man rsync269.pdf' file was actually a symbolic link (created with `ln -s`). Note that the `select` command's result describes this file as an 'alias file' rather than as a 'document file'. The third item is now a folder.

**Update:** Added support for folders

```
tell application "Finder"
    set tPath to (insertion location)
    --> folder "random-storage" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder"
    set fileNameList to paragraphs of (the clipboard)
    --> {"man rsync269.pdf", "man unzip.pdf", "man pages"}
    
    set tOutput to {}
    repeat with ii from 1 to count of fileNameList
        try -- if file (includes alias files)
            set end of tOutput to file (item ii of fileNameList) of tPath
        on error -- if folder (technically, if not a file)
            set end of tOutput to folder (item ii of fileNameList) of tPath
        end try
        --> alias file man rsync269.pdf of folder "random-storage" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    end repeat
    
    select tOutput
    --> {alias file "man rsync269.pdf" of folder "random-storage" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder", document file "man unzip.pdf" of folder "random-storage" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder", folder "man pages" of folder "random-storage" of folder "username" of folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder"}
end tell
```

Alternatively, I think this would likely also work if you coerced everything to text and then prefaced each reference with *file* (i.e. composing a file url).

Comment: Eureka! The thing I was doing was all based on the (mis)understanding that I needed to convert the files to the text of the filenames and then prepend the filepath as a string to the name of each file and then reveal each file at the new location. This is so much simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Next step: Finding a way to compare the clipboard to what exists in a folder so that, if/when Finder makes a duplicate of a pasted file with a new name (ending with either " copy" or " 2", etc.), that I can skip the script to select the pasted files by name in those cases, and leave it to Finder to select the newly-created duplicate files.

Comment: I just realized this doesn't work if the copied items are folders! Is there some way it could be modified so it still works with folders too?

Comment: @MaxWell I've added a check to deal with folders. Regarding duplicates, I think that would be a separate problem. There would be myriad edge cases, for example… what if you had a " 2" and a " 4" already in the target folder. In any case, you wouldn't really be dealing with the clipboard anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've also added the following to the end of the script in the accepted answer in order to make the debug text for the paths of files that were copy/pasted and selected in Finder easier to read.

```
set debugtext to {}
repeat with j from 1 to count of tOutput
    set end of debugtext to (POSIX path of ((item j of tOutput) as string)) & return
end repeat
return debugtext
```